# Get consistent sort order when passing filepath to `Send to` despite file selection order

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters

Try to mess with mass rename thing, so the file name order is important

Then I found (yet another) weird thing of Windows...

Say we have 5 files named `1.txt, 2.txt, 11.txt, 22.txt, 100.txt` and try to do something with a batch script `order.bat` with content like:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a Count=0
for %%I IN (%*) DO (
 Echo Arg #!Count! = %%~nI
 REM do something
 set /a Count+=1
)
Endlocal
pause
```

#### 1. Explorer Order

That's how files are ordered in Explorer with the order you set, by default it's `By file name, Ascend`.

The order of file is `1.txt, 2.txt, 11.txt, 22.txt, 100.txt`

#### 2. Drag'n'drop Order

Let's drag those 5 txt files onto `order.bat`, the output is (no matter how you select those files)

```
Arg #0 = 100
Arg #1 = 1
Arg #2 = 2
Arg #3 = 11
Arg #4 = 22
```

#### 3. Sendto Order

Magic part coming. If you drop a shortcut of `order.bat` (order.bat - shortcut.lnk) to `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`, you can select files and right click and select `Send to` then click `order.bat - shortcut`

If you select `1.txt`...`100.txt` one by one in explorer order (by holding ctrl and click each file), you get same result as drag and drop:

```
Arg #0 = 100
Arg #1 = 1
Arg #2 = 2
Arg #3 = 11
Arg #4 = 22
```

But if you select those file one by one in reverse order(`100.txt` then `22.txt`...`1.txt`) then send to `order.bat - shortcut`, you get:

```
Arg #0 = 2
Arg #1 = 11
Arg #2 = 22
Arg #3 = 100
Arg #4 = 1
```

A smaller test, if you select `1.txt` then `2.txt` then send to `order.bat - shortcut`, you get

```
Arg #0 = 2
Arg #1 = 1
```

If you select `2.txt` then `1.txt`, you get:

```
Arg #0 = 1
Arg #1 = 2
```

---

Now the question, is it possible to pass file names as parameter to `order.bat` in `Explorer Order`? Or at least in `Drag'n'drop Order` when using `Send To`? Or the very least, keep the order when using `Send To` consistent?

Comment: There is no sorting mechanism to match the 'intuitive file sorting' shown in Windows Explorer. You would need to create some very convoluted code, possibly with the help of another scripting language, or use a third party utility.

Comment: Some sort order might even depend on the file system (FAT, NTFS, CDFS, etc.)…